# Invoke functions that return a mix of rvalues and lvalue tuple without the lvalue references decaying into values?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Minimum Example:

```cpp
struct RValue {
  int x = 12;
  auto operator*() const { return x; }
} x;

struct LValueRef {
  int y = 13;
  auto &operator*() { return y; }
} y;

auto z = std::make_tuple(x, y);

auto f() {
  // Replace std::make_tuple with what? 
  return std::apply([](auto &...x) { return std::make_tuple(*x...); }, z);
}

int main() {
    auto [a, b] = f();
}
```

I would like f to return a `std::tuple<int, int&>`, where it is currently returning a `std::tuple<int, int>`. This is supposed to run on an arbitrary tuple z, where elements on de-referencing can give r-values and l-value references.

Originally, all elements of the tuple z were similar to the `LValueRef` class, so I used `std::tie` to return the tuple in the form required.

I essentially need to call `std::make_tuple`, but wrap a `std::ref` around the elements which are originally l-vale references. This could be done as the following pseudo code shows:

```cpp
  if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
    return std::ref(t);
  else
    return t;
```

I don't know exactly how to write this in the `std::apply` invocation, but maybe I can transform the types of the `std::tuple` and create return `return std::tuple<Ts_transformed...>(*x...);`

What is the ideal way to get this behavior?

---

I briefly tried to use `std::forward_as_tuple` without understanding how it works (it compiled). this caused r-values to become r-value references and l-values to become l-value references (i.e., returns `std::tuple<int &&, int &>`. However, when using this, I believe I was accessing a temporary after it went out of scope, and that isn't correct. I'm not sure what exactly is happening here, and why I cannot use the `int &&` value?

---

I was originally trying to write an adaptor similar to Python's `range` and `zip`. The function I am trying to write above de-references a tuple of iterators. Originally the iterators all returned lvalue-references, so `std::tie` worked fine, but I wanted this to also work with iterators that return rvalues.

```
template <typename... WrappedRanges> class ZipWrappedRange {
  std::tuple<WrappedRanges...> r_;
public:
  class iterator {
    std::tuple<typename WrappedRanges::iterator...> its_;
  public:
    explicit iterator(typename WrappedRanges::iterator &&...it) : its_(std::make_tuple(it...)) {}
    explicit iterator(std::tuple<typename WrappedRanges::iterator...> &&it) : its_(it) {}

    auto operator*() const {
      // I need to modify this to allow for cases where (*x) returns rvalues and not just l-value references.
      return std::apply([](auto &...x) { return std::tie((*x)...); }, its_);
    }
  };
  ...
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent C++20/23 `<ranges>`? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view

Comment: Yes, at least in part. I cannot use C++23 in this project and I don't want to be dependent on compiler versions to include gcc's header.

Comment: Did you try `range-v3`? It is the prototype of `<ranges>` maintained by **Eric Neibler**. https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3

Comment: You could write a helper function that does the `constexpr` trick, then do `std::make_tuple(my_ref_wrapper(*x)...);`

Comment: I tried the helper function trick again, and I realised I was originally passing it by value. It works if i take it as a r-value reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::make_tuple` might be replaced with `tuple` constructor where you provide types explicitly:

```
auto f() {
  return std::apply([](auto&...x) { return std::tuple<decltype(*x)...>{*x...}; },
                    z);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6faanKGYd)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution that uses the constexpr wrapper function trick.

```cpp
template <typename T> auto get_value(T &&t) {
  if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
    return std::ref(t);
  else
    return t;
}

auto f() {
  return std::apply([](auto &...x) { return std::make_tuple(get_value(*x)...); }, z);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TsqrKK47T)